# How to round smoothly percentage in JS

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

I have an object containing decimals values : `evo`, `meteo` and `usage`
I try to display this values with three conditions :

- values can be positive and negative
- values must be displayed as percentage without any decimals
- (A) must be true

(A):   `Math.round(meteo*100)+Math.round(usage*100) = Math.round(evo*100)`

For example, if we apply A with to these values

```
{evo: 0.1466, meteo: 0.1231, usage: 0.0235}
```

We will get unvalid percentages :

```
evo: 15%
meteo: 12%
usage: 2%
```

Because values are rounded, sometimes (A) isn't verified.
I am working on a getSmooth function to adjust rounded values to get the equation (A) always verified.

```
var smooth = getSmooth(Math.round(evo*100), Math.round(meteo*100), Math.round(usage*100);

function getSmooth(evo, meteo, usage){
    // case we need to incremente something
    if( Math.abs(evo) > Math.abs(meteo) + Math.abs(usage) ){
        // case we need to incremente usage
        if( Math.abs(meteo) > Math.abs(usage) ){
            (usage > 0) ? usage++ : usage--;
        }
        // case we need to incremente meteo
        else{
            (meteo > 0) ? meteo++ : meteo--;
        }
    }
    // case we need to decremente something
    else{
        // case we need to decremente usage
        if( Math.abs(meteo) > Math.abs(usage) ){
            (usage > 0) ? usage-- : usage++;
        }
        // case we need to decremente meteo
        else{
            (meteo > 0) ? meteo-- : meteo++;
        }
    }

    return {
        evo: evo,
        meteo: meteo,
        usage: usage
    };
}
```

My function isn't workind well, and it does handle only +1 incrementation/decrementation.
I am pretty sure I am doing it the hard way.

Is there an easier way to achieve that task ?

Comment: If you round first and then add I don't believe that you can ever guarantee equality (what you are calling "A must be true".)

Comment: Math.round(val*100)/100;

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot show the percentages to a higher precision?

Comment: Do you have an example where your function isn't working properly ?

Comment: @RowlandShaw, the available UX space can only display two digits, MaximePeloquin, I gave one already,

Comment: @DavidHoelzer next line you can read (A) ;)

Comment: @BigDong  I did read A.  That's why I said that you can't expect A to always be true.  Rounding is not commutative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
function getSmooth(meteo, usage) {
    meteo = Math.round(meteo*100);
    usage = Math.round(usage*100);
    return {
        evo: (meteo + usage) / 100,
        meteo: meteo / 100,
        usage: usage / 100
    };
}
```

to test for errors in calculations in `evo` separate from your visualisation logic:

```
var evo, meteo, usage;
// ...
// do the error handling
var eps = 1e-4; // some float precision epsilon
if(Math.abs(evo - (meteo + usage)) > eps) {
     // there's an error in evo...
}
// now do the processing
var smooth = getSmooth(meteo, usage);
// continue with smooth...
```

Comment: nice one, but I prefere not to use this. If we have an error of calc on evo, we won't see it using this interface.

Comment: @BigDong just check at the calling level

Comment: I am doing it already as report log, but still, the operator need to notice.

Comment: @BigDong you can override the evo in the error case, but you probably want to do something different than showing an erroneous result to the operator...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach to it if you want to keep the **accuracy** of the value of `evo` and not calculate it based on the total of `meteo` and `usage`. (It's a bit uglier than using `evo = metro + usage`)

Look at what the decimal is for `meteo` and `usage`, then use `.ceil()` or `.floor()` depending on the result.

```
var smooth = getSmooth(evo, meteo, usage);

function getSmooth(evo, meteo, usage){

    evo   *= 100;
    meteo *= 100;
    usage *= 100;

    var meteo_decimal = meteo % 1;
    var usage_decimal = usage % 1;

    evo = Math.round(evo);

    if( meteo_decimal > usage_decimal ) {
        meteo = Math.ceil(meteo);
        usage = Math.floor(usage);
    } else {
        meteo = Math.floor(meteo);
        usage = Math.ceil(usage);
    }

    return {
        evo: evo / 100,
        meteo: meteo / 100,
        usage: usage / 100
    };
}
```

Comment: Ah yeah good point, going to have to rethink this one. Trying to think of a different thats different to yours and contains the value of evo.

Comment: Changed it now but it just gets uglier.

Comment: Right that should do it, but still the best way to do it is as you have previously answered. Was trying to do it using the real value of evo just out of curiosity.